# Tool to detect language of text?

Tags: language, auto-detect

Is there a tool that can detect the language of the text of several paragraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many tools around to do this, the first one thatI can think of is Google's own:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#language_detect

- In java, there is http://textcat.sourceforge.net/
- In Ruby https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage
- In Perl http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Lingua-Identify-0.29/lib/Lingua/Identify.pm
  etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: The language_detect tool by google seems promising, I have to do this for more than one text. I see some code there but I don't know whether I can run it on my machine.

Comment: google API probably has limits on the amount of queries  you can send, so you might need to use one of the other libraries to do it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The `file` tool has a bunch of heuristics for guessing file types, including one that reports "English text". I don't know if it knows about other human languages, but it definitely could be upgraded to guess between them.